# VSCode Insider Jupyter notebook "run code by line"

Tags: jupyter, visual-studio-code

I am working with VS-Code insiders edition (v1.54.0).  Installed Jupyter Extension version v2021.3.600686576. Separately, I am running the normal VS-Code application (v1.53.2), using Jupyter extension v2021.2.603412351.

Using Jupyter Notebooks for iterative development...
One of the capabilities that does not show up in the Insiders Edition is the 'Run code by Line' capability that typically shows up at the top of each cell (An icon) in the Jupyter Notebook in the 'regular' application.  This features enables a line-by-line walkthrough of the code **within** a cell, similar to a standard IDE debugger.  I can use the dataviews and active variables windows to give me a basic debug capability within Notebook (vs python standard debugger, or exporting Notebook to Python file and using VScode debugger).

I am not sure if there is some setting that precludes this ... or whether it is a Jupyter extension issue/change or a VS-code Insiders implementation change.
I have searched through the open and closed issues on Github and browsed release notes and changelogs, but not see anything pertinent.

Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: See the update at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68242094/836330 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_59.md#jupyter-run-by-line.  `"jupyter.experimental.debugging": true`

Answer (score 1):

Run by line hasn't been implemented for Native Notebooks yet. It's on our backlog though—feel free to subscribe to this issue for updates https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/255

Comment: Thanks. I subscribed to this issue.  Is there a way to switch between the 'Native Notebook' and the 'Jupyter notebook' within the Insiders edition?

Comment: Yes, you can set "jupyter.experiments.optOutFrom": ["NativeNotebookEditor"] in your user settings.json to opt out of native notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

Run by Line is implemented in VS Code now.
It has the preset shortcut F10.

[VS code run by line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2dPn.png)