# Debugging of Jupyter notebooks in VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using Visual Studio Code Insiders to work on Jupyter Notebook files. In the default version of VSCode it is possible to debug Jupyter notebook cells. Unfortunately, this is not the case with the insiders version.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66412377/vscode-insider-jupyter-notebook-run-code-by-line/67966861#67966861) describes the possibility to switch between the "Native Notebook" and the "Jupyter Notebook".
In my case, adding the line "jupyter.experiments.optOutFrom": ["NativeNotebookEditor"] to my settings.json file and reopen the editor leads to the following error message:

> Extension activation failed, run the 'Developer: Toggle Developer Tools' command for more information.

I would be grateful if there is any idea what this error could be due to.

Comment: Debugging is currently in process for native notebooks, but yes it's not there yet. In Developer: Toggle Developer Tools do you see any errors in the logging?

Comment: One thing to check, look in your settings JSON file. And look to see if there is a "workbench.editorAssociations" setting. If there is, you might need to clear that after removing yourself from the native experiment.

Comment: Perfect, the tip with the "workbench.editorAssociations" solved the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I just added that comment as an answer (didn't want to add it as an answer unless I was sure that it was working for you). If you could mark that as the answer that might help anyone else searching for this issue. Glad you are unblocked now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment above as an answer so that it can be marked as an answer:

One thing to check, look in your settings JSON file. And look to see if there is a "workbench.editorAssociations" setting. If there is, you might need to clear that after removing yourself from the native experiment.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Ian's advice to clear the "workbench.editorAssociations" setting.

After that I had to create a new ipynb by running the command: `create new blank notebook` (Shift-Ctrl-P) before my existing notebooks were properly interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled the Jupyter extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that problem by inserting `"enable-proposed-api": ["ms-toolsai.jupyter"]`  in the start settings of vs code. So press CTRL+ALT+P -> "Preference: Configure Runtime Arguments" then insert the upper line. After that restart vscode.

[Reference](https://www.pythonfixing.com/2022/03/fixed-jupyter-extension-for-vscode-on.html)